# xsl check if color is a name or hex

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Below, `@color` can be a color name or a hex value. Is there a way in xslt to tell them apart in a test? Like some sort of built-in function or something?

```
<xsl:when test="/path/@color" />
```

can be `red` or `ff0000`

I need to know whether to concatenate the `#` symbol if it is a hex value.

Comment: Please provide an example of both, and state if you can use XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I'm limited to xslt-1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use:

```
<xsl:if test="translate(/path/@color, '123456789abcdef', '000000000000000')='000000'">
```

This is assuming hex colors are in lower-case and padded to 6 digits.

However, there is still a small chance of a false positive - for example, if a color happens to be named "facade", there is no way to tell it from a `#facade` hex value.